# Grails query to filter on association and only return matching entities

Tags: sql, grails, grails-orm

I have the following 1 - M (one way) relationship:

```
Customer (1) -> (M) Address
```

I am trying to filter the addresses for a specific customer that contain certain text e.g.

```
def results = Customer.withCriteria {
    eq "id", 995L
    addresses {
        ilike 'description', '%text%'
    }
}
```

The problem is that this returns the Customer and when I in turn access the "addresses" it gives me the full list of addresses rather than the filtered list of addresses.

It's not possible for me to use `Address.withCriteria` as I can't access the association table from the criteria query.

I'm hoping to avoid reverting to a raw SQL query as this would mean not being able to use a lot functionality that's in place to build up criteria queries in a flexible and reusable manner.

Would love to hear any thoughts ...

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason for the different behavior in 2.1 is documented [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/single.html#persistenceFeatures)

Specifically this point:

> The previous default of LEFT JOIN for criteria queries across associations is now INNER JOIN.

IIRC, Hibernate doesn't eagerly load associations when you use an inner join.

Looks like you can use `createAlias` to specify an outer join [example here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/GORM-criteria-how-to-revert-to-old-quot-left-outer-join-quot-behaviour-for-a-query-td4630152.html):

My experience with this particular issue is from experience with NHibernate, so I can't really shed more light on getting it working correctly than that. I'll happily delete this answer if it turns out to be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def results = Customer.createCriteria().listDistinct() {
    eq('id', 995L)
    addresses {
        ilike('description', '%Z%')
    }
}
```

This gives you the Customer object that has the correct id and any matching addresses, and only those addresses than match.

You could also use this query (slightly modified) to get all customers that have a matching address:

```
def results = Customer.createCriteria().listDistinct() {
    addresses {
        ilike('description', '%Z%')
    }
}

results.each {c->
    println "Customer " + c.name
    c.addresses.each {address->
        println "Address " + address.description
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Here are the domain classes and the way I added the addresses:

```
class Customer {
  String name
  static hasMany = [addresses: PostalAddress]
  static constraints = {
  }
}
class PostalAddress {
  String description
  static belongsTo = [customer: Customer]
  static constraints = {
  }
}
//added via Bootstrap for testing
def init = { servletContext ->
    def custA = new Customer(name: 'A').save(failOnError: true)
    def custB = new Customer(name: 'B').save(failOnError: true)
    def custC = new Customer(name: 'C').save(failOnError: true)

    def add1 = new PostalAddress(description: 'Z1', customer: custA).save(failOnError: true)
    def add2 = new PostalAddress(description: 'Z2', customer: custA).save(failOnError: true)
    def add3 = new PostalAddress(description: 'Z3', customer: custA).save(failOnError: true)
    def add4 = new PostalAddress(description: 'W4', customer: custA).save(failOnError: true)
    def add5 = new PostalAddress(description: 'W5', customer: custA).save(failOnError: true)
    def add6 = new PostalAddress(description: 'W6', customer: custA).save(failOnError: true)

}
```

When I run this I get the following output:

```
Customer A
Address Z3
Address Z1
Address Z2
```

Comment: All the addresses are printed rather then only the ones matching the query. The query is really returning distinct customers, which is fine. I'm looking for an efficient way to find matching addresses for a customer without having to iterate over each address after I get the query results back.

Comment: What version of Grails are you using?  How are you accessing the addresses once you have the Customer instance?  When I mock this up (using Grails 1.3.7 or 2.1) I assign 6 addresses to the particular customer I want to use to test - only 3 of them have the matching text in the description.  ONLY those 3 addresses come back when I run this.

Comment: I'm using 2.0.3, I also tried the code above on 2.1.0 and I get the following output: `Customer A
Address Z1
Address W6
Address Z3
Address W5
Address Z2
Address W4`

Comment: My apologies - I didn't look at this correctly in 2.1.  It behaves exactly the way you say - shows all the addresses; in 1.3.7 it only lists the addresses that match. I'll update if I can figure it out.  Sorry!